# R: transform a dataframe into another based on rank

Tags: r

I have this df corresponding to the rank of citation of each variety:

```
variety <- c("variety1","variety2","variety3","variety4","variety5")
people1 <- c(1, NA, 3, 2, NA)
people2 <- c(4, 3, 2, 1, NA)
people3 <- c(3, 2, NA, 4, 1)
df <- data.frame(variety, people1, people2, people3); df
```

I want to create instead a data frame without the first column. (easy enough :-D)
And where all the following ones rather list the varieties cited by all the people in the proper order.
It would look like this:

```
people1 <- c("variety1", "variety3", "variety2",NA,NA)
people2 <- c("variety4", "variety3", "variety2", "variety1", NA)
people3 <- c("variety3", "variety2", "variety4", "variety1", NA)
df2 <- data.frame(people1, people2, people3); df2
```

So the list would become each variety names cited in the right order based on their rank in the initial df.

NAs could be removed such that columns would not have the same length (fine for the software where I plan to submit this)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, we can't have a non-rectangular data frame, but here's a `list` with the entries you want and the `NA`s removed:

```
lapply(df[-1], \(x) df$variety[x[!is.na(x)]])
# $people1
# [1] "variety1" "variety3" "variety2"
# 
# $people2
# [1] "variety4" "variety3" "variety2" "variety1"
# 
# $people3
# [1] "variety3" "variety2" "variety4" "variety1"
```

If you need it as a data frame we can pad the lengths:

```
result = lapply(df[-1], \(x) df$variety[x[!is.na(x)]])
n = max(lengths(result))
result = lapply(result, \(x) {length(x) = n; x}) |> as.data.frame()
result
#    people1  people2  people3
# 1 variety1 variety4 variety3
# 2 variety3 variety3 variety2
# 3 variety2 variety2 variety4
# 4     <NA> variety1 variety1
```

Comment: sounds good, thanks!
then, can't we transform into a df, even if the lists are of different length?

Comment: If the lists were the same length after `NA` removal you could wrap in `as.data.frame()`. With different length lists you can't make it a data frame. You could pad the lists so they are the same length and then convert to a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
list2DF(lapply(df[-1], \(x)df$variety[c(na.omit(x), x[is.na(x)])]))

   people1  people2  people3
1 variety1 variety4 variety3
2 variety3 variety3 variety2
3 variety2 variety2 variety4
4     <NA> variety1 variety1
5     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to what this does?

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.