# Dataframe with ranks into data frame with ordered list

Tags: r

I have this data frame which lists the citation ranks for each variety across three people:

```
df <- data.frame(
    variety = c("variety1","variety2","variety3","variety4","variety5"),
    people1 = c(1, NA, 3, 2, NA),
    people2 = c(4, 3, 2, 1, NA),
    people3 = c(3, 2, 5, 4, 1)
)
> df
   variety people1 people2 people3
1 variety1       1       4       3
2 variety2      NA       3       2
3 variety3       3       2       5
4 variety4       2       1       4
5 variety5      NA      NA       1
```

I want a list or a data frame like this. Where the varieties are listed in rank order for each person.

```
   people1  people2  people3
1 variety1 variety4 variety5
2 variety3 variety3 variety2
3 variety4 variety2 variety1
4     <NA> variety1 variety4
5     <NA>     <NA> variety3
```

Comment: Why are posting this question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75259703/r-transform-a-dataframe-into-another-based-on-rank .You could have edited the previous one if needed

Comment: it's a different issue if you look out the output I want

Comment: As for the last question you asked, what have you already tried?

Comment: of course I checked! this is another issue, look at the output here ;-) thanks

Comment: Can you explain more clearly/explicitly the logic of how the input and output columns are related?

Comment: sure! Thanks for your willingness to help.
For instance, looking at the input, people1 has first mentioned variety1, then variety4, then, variety3. So I want the output to have those three varieties in that order for the column people1. Same for the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` are really useful for restructuring data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = people1:people3,
        names_to = 'person',
        values_to = 'rank'
    ) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(rank)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        id_cols = rank,
        names_from = 'person', 
        values_from = 'variety'
    ) %>% 
    arrange(rank)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
   rank people1  people2  people3 
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 variety1 variety4 variety5
2     2 variety4 variety3 variety2
3     3 variety3 variety2 variety1
4     4 NA       variety1 variety4
5     5 NA       NA       variety3
```